# Multiple instances of serial object in python on same com port

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

I am using [pyserial](/questions/tagged/pyserial) to handle serial communications with devices in a multi-drop network.  There will be multiple devices all on the same COM port, addressed using a device ID.

I have created a class to handle communications with the devices, and have a higher level main loop that uses this class to control all of the devices simultaneously.

In the main loop, I instantiate a serial object using `serial.Serial(port, baud_rate)` for communications with one of the devices in the network.

A few questions:

- Can you have multiple serial objects utilizing the same COM port and baud rate?
- Or do I need to pass the same serial object around when read/writing amongst devices?
- If a serial object has already been opened, outside of the scope of one particular object, can you somehow query the COM port for if there is already serial comms happening, and at what baud rate?

Comment: You probably want to pass around a shared COM port reference. You'll need to have your application manage that shared reference so weird things do not happen.